# Unable to post from Register Form

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have implemented a register form in NodeJS. i couldn't get data from register form when i click submit button. I don't know why it has happened ! please help me out.

user.js stored in routes file.
userregister.ejs stored in views file.

```
// users.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

 //Get Login
 router.get('/login', function(req,res){
 res.render('userlogin');
 });

 //Get Register
 router.get('/register', function(req,res){
 res.render('userregister',{title:'Register'});
 });

 //Post Register
 router.post('/register', function(req,res){
 var nam = req.body.name;
 console.log(nam);
 });

 module.exports = router;


  //useregister.ejs

     <form method="POST" action="/register" >
          <div class="form-group">

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required 
      class="form-control input-lg" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" 
     required class="form-control input-lg" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required 
     class="form-control input-lg" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input- 
     lg" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control input-lg" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
          <div>
            <p> Have an account :  <a href="/login">Login Here </a> </p>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but you've missed a few key steps:

1. Before you can use the router, you need to create the app and use the router

   - At the top: const app = express()
   - At the bottom:

     - app.use('/',router)
     - app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening')
2. To read the form you need a parser

   - var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
   - app.use(bodyParser.json());
   - var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
3. The parser is a middleware, so you will need to add it to the route

   - router.post('/register', **urlencodedParser**, function(req,res){
4. Don't forget to respond to the browser after console.log, or else the app will just hang.

Here is working code:

```
// users.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

//Get Login
router.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('userlogin');
});

//Get Register
router.get('/register', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/userregister.ejs');
});

//Post Register
router.post('/register', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    var nam = req.body.name;
    console.log(nam);
    res.send(nam);
});

app.use('/',router)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Oh man you are correct  ! I forgot to add body-parser in app. Js file....!  Anyways thanks buddy